# 3 red, 3 blue and 3 green beads are arranged in a circle. What is the probability that each bead has at least one neighboring bead of other color?

Tags: combinatorics

All possible arrangements of the beads in the circle are 9!.
If we start from a specific bead to which we assign number 1 (starting point), then the number of possible arrangements of the 3 different colors is 
$\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} = \frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$

It seems to me that it is impossible for ALL beads to have neighboring beads of the same color - am I missing something?

Comment: OK so we want to exclude the arrangements that either include at least one block of 3 consecutive of the same color, or a block of 2 at the beginning and the same one at the end, or a block of 2 at the end and 1 at the beginning?

Comment: Yes. You should exclude arrangements with three cyclically connected consecutive beads of the same color.

Comment: The arrangements that contain one block of 3 consecutive of the same color are $\binom{3}{1}\frac{7!}{3!3!}$ - is this so?

Comment: Could you provide the answer?

Comment: OK so I find that the requested probability is (1680-20*7*3-2*20*3)/1680 = 0.6785. Can anyone tell me if it is correct?

Comment: "All possible arrangements of the beads in the circle are 9!." It depends on definition. If you consider all arrangements connected by a cyclic shift equivalent, the number is different. Besides you should more precisely define the process of arrangement, so that the probability is well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all red beads have a neighbor of other color if and only if the red beads are placed on consecutive spots.

---

Let $R$ denote the event that the red beads are placed on consecutive spots.

Let $B$ denote the event that the blue beads are placed on consecutive spots.

Let $G$ denote the event that the green beads are placed on consecutive spots.

Then to be found is $1-\mathsf P(R\cup B\cup G)$ and with [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry we find that this equals:

$$\begin{aligned}1-3\mathsf{P}(R)+3\mathsf{P}(R\cap B)-\mathsf{P}(R\cap B\cap G) & =1-\mathsf{P}\left(R\right)\left[3-3\mathsf{P}\left(B\mid R\right)+\mathsf{P}(B\cap G\mid R)\right]\\
 & =1-\frac{9}{\binom{9}{3}}\left[3-3\frac{4}{\binom{6}{3}}+\frac{2}{\binom{6}{3}}\right]\\
 & =\frac{41}{56}\\
 & \approx0,732142857
\end{aligned}
$$

Observe that there are $\binom93$ distinct triples of spots and by $9$ of them the spots are consecutive.

This explains $\mathsf P(R)=9/\binom93$.

Under condition of event $R$ there are $6$ consecutive spots left so there are $\binom63$ triples in total of which $4$ are consecutive and $2$ of which are such that the events $G$ and $B$ will both occur ifthey are possessed by e.g. blue beads.